# SQL Server : INSERT "cartesian product"

Tags: sql-server, insert, cartesian-product

I have a data table with destinations and LAT/LON data (~100K records)

```
DESTINATIONS {
 id,
 lat,
 lon,
 ...
}
```

Now I need to insert distances into a new table...

```
DISTANCES {
 id_a,
 id_b,
 distance
}
```

What's the best way to do that?

1. I don't need all data (cartesian product), only the 100 closest.
2. No duplicates (a_id+b_id == b_id+a_id), e.g. [NYC:Chicago] == [Chicago:NYC] (same distance)
3. Not by itself (a_id != b_id), because it 0 miles from [NYC:NYC] ;)

This is the calculation (in kilometers/meters):

```
ROUND(111045 
* DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(A.lat)) 
* COS(RADIANS(B.lat)) 
* COS(RADIANS(A.lon) - RADIANS(B.lon)) 
+ SIN(RADIANS(A.lat)) 
* SIN(RADIANS(B.lat)))),0)
AS 'distance'
```

Okay, the JOIN is no problem, but how can I implement the three "filters"?

Maybe with a *WHILE loop* and *SUBSELECT LIMIT/TOP 100 ORDER BY distance ASC*?

Or is it also possible to **INSERT by JOIN?**

Does somebody have a idea?

Comment: Google and learn about the `INSERT..SELECT` structure in SQL.

Comment: SUB-SELECTs are to slowly for 5'000'000'000 results! :/

Comment: Any SELECT that you can write can be used in a SELECT..INSERT.   You ask if it is possible to "insert by join".   If you learn about this structure, you will have your answer.

Comment: But how to limit the 100 nearest for each record? - That's my main problem. :/

Comment: INSERT-SELECT-SELECT??
 
 
INSERT {
 SELECT {
  SELECT TOP 100 {
   ...
  }
 }
}

Comment: INSERT..SELECT TOP 100..

Comment: okay, I know the LIMIT syntax, ... I need a foreach*100 syntax :( THAT is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Psuedocode:

```
INSERT INTO [newTable] (ColumnList...)
SELECT TOP 100 a.id, b.id, DistanceFormula(a.id, b.id)
FROM Destination a
CROSS JOIN Destination b
WHERE a.id<b.id
ORDER BY DistanceFormula(a.id, b.id) ASC
```

EDIT to get 100 b for every a:

```
INSERT INTO [newTable] (ColumnList...)
SELECT a.id, b.id, DistanceFormula(a.id, b.id)
FROM Destination a
INNER JOIN Destination b
  ON b.id=(
    SELECT TOP 100 c.id
    FROM Destination c
    WHERE a.id<c.id
    ORDER BY DistanceFormula(a.id, c.id) ASC
)
```

Comment: but that just returns 100 results, right? I need all*100 results :/

Comment: What do you mean?   For each a, you need the closest 100 b?

Comment: for each record (destination) I need the closest 100 destinations

Comment: Well that's different.  Ok, then how should your req #2 be handled?  If you already have New York > Chicago, then do you still want 100 destinations for Chicago, or just 99?

Comment: Yes. :)

- In the end I need 100 results when I ask for New York in the new table.

- Maybe... if ( a.id > b.id ) ...so I only have 50% of the cartesian product.

Comment: The first SELECT "A" is limited 100 (?) --- And the last "SELECT C" gives more than one result back, but there is "id = (...)" (?)

Comment: I meant to take the TOP 100 out of the outer select.   I will fix that in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified it (distcalc)...

```
INSERT INTO [DISTANCES] (id_a, id_b, distance)
    SELECT
        A.id,
        B.id,
        25 /*ROUND(111045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(A.geo_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(B.geo_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(A.geo_lon) - RADIANS(B.geo_lon)) + SIN(RADIANS(A.geo_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(B.geo_lat)))),0)*/
    FROM [DESTINATIONS] AS A
    INNER JOIN [DESTINATIONS] AS B
        ON b.id IN(
            SELECT TOP 100
                C.id
            FROM [DESTINATIONS] AS C
            WHERE
                A.id < C.id
            ORDER BY A.id /*ROUND(111045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(A.geo_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(C.geo_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(A.geo_lon) - RADIANS(C.geo_lon)) + SIN(RADIANS(A.geo_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(C.geo_lat)))),0)*/ ASC
        )
```

You mean like this?

Comment: Yes, that's the structure anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. That works. :)

But it is definitely too slow!

I'll program a routine that returns only the 100 nearest results on request.
And another (sub) routine will insert/update these (program-sided) results with timestamp into the distances table, so that it's possible to accessed to any existing results by the next call.

But thank you very very much! :)